# Python: synthetic data generation by sampling column values for a new row

Tags: python

I am working with the open-source `adult` dataset in Python. It looks like the following snippet, although despite the formatting below, it is actually in a nice Pandas DataFrame. I would like to generate more observations using some sampling methods, namely, a new observation with feature values that are sampled from each column rather than sampling existing rows. How would I do that in Python? I would like to generate 10M rows.

```
    age workclass   fnlwgt  education   education-num   marital-status  occupation  relationship    race    sex capital-gain    capital-loss    hours-per-week  native-country  income
0   39  State-gov   77516   Bachelors   13  Never-married   Adm-clerical    Not-in-family   White   Male    2174    0   40  United-States   <=50K
1   50  Self-emp-not-inc    83311   Bachelors   13  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial Husband White   Male    0   0   13  United-States   <=50K
2   38  Private 215646  HS-grad 9   Divorced    Handlers-cleaners   Not-in-family   White   Male    0   0   40  United-States   <=50K
3   53  Private 234721  11th    7   Married-civ-spouse  Handlers-cleaners   Husband Black   Male    0   0   40  United-States   <=50K
4   28  Private 338409  Bachelors   13  Married-civ-spouse  Prof-specialty  Wife    Black   Female  0   0   40  Cuba    <=50K
```

Comment: You'll be destroying the correlation between columns by sampling columns independently and then creating more data. @user2205916

Comment: @Vishnudev for my purposes, that's ok.

Comment: Use `.sample()` on a series.

Comment: @Vishnudev can you write a complete solution?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Vishnudev Unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def generate_synthetic(df,n_samples=10):
    """Generate n_samples number of synthetic data by sampling each column in independent manner"""
    synthetic_data=[]
    for i in range(n_samples):
        synthetic_data.append(df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1),axis=0).sum(axis=0))
    return pd.DataFrame(synthetic_data)
```

this seemed to work for me. It takes quite a time though